# How start & stop MAMP PRO using command line?

Tags: macos, apache, localhost, mamp

I am trying to find a way by which I can start and stop MAMP PRO's Apache and mysql using command line.
So far whatever I have search has only helped me start MAMP PRO.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

http://pastebin.com/avn0BFap

Save the script and give executable rights such as: `chmod +x start.sh`

Then use it like `./start.sh Start` or `./start.sh Stop` or `./start.sh Restart`

Answer (score 50):

As of at least MAMP 3.0.6, the following works for both Free and Pro versions:

Open MAMP Pro or Free, depending on the one you use:

Pro:
`open /Applications/MAMP\ PRO/MAMP\ PRO.app/`

Free:
`open /Applications/MAMP/MAMP.app/`

Then, cd into MAMP/bin:

```
cd /Applications/MAMP/bin
```

To start Apache & MySQL:

```
./start.sh
```

To stop Apache & MySQL:

```
./stop.sh
```

Note that you might need to sudo the commands above.

Comment: This works for MAMP, but I'm looking for something for MAMP PRO

Comment: If you're running a linux environment you can add this to your `.bash_profile` for quick on and off: `alias startmamp='open /Applications/MAMP/MAMP.app;bash /Applications/MAMP/bin/start.sh'`
`alias stopmamp='bash /Applications/MAMP/bin/stop.sh'`

Answer (score 18):

After much trial and error:

Note that I have my ports set to the application's respective defaults (Apache: 80, MySQL: 3306), and as such these commands reflect that, AND you must use `sudo` with Apache (which you will in MAMP as well if you're using port 80).

### Apache

> sudo /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/httpd -f "/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/httpd.conf" -k start
>
> sudo /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/httpd -f "/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/httpd.conf" -k stop
>
> sudo /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/httpd -f "/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/httpd.conf" -k restart

### MySQL

*To start MySQL:*

> sh -c '/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/my.cnf --port=3306 --socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock --user=alex --pid-file=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid --log-error=/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log.err --tmpdir=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/tmpdir --datadir=/Library/Application\ Support/appsolute/MAMP\ PRO/db/mysql &'

(for some reason you must hit *enter* again to regain your prompt)

*To stop MySQL:*

> sh -c '/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin -u root -proot --socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock shutdown'

As a bonus, the indicators in the MAMP PRO.app GUI show the correct status of these apps in real time, so you can continue to rely on that.

I have MAMP PRO v2.0.3.

Comment: This works mostly; but then phpMyAdmin cannot write sessions...Is there another way?

Comment: Are you using sudo as mentioned in the answer?

Comment: Is there a way to specify the ports here? You said you use 80 and "[the] commands reflect that", but I see nowhere where you specify the ports.

And also, the reason you must type enter is because you used a "&" at the end, I know the comment is almost 3 years old but whatever.

Comment: Thanks! I added this to my ~/.bash_profile:
`mpache() {
  sudo /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/httpd -f "/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/httpd.conf" -k $1
}`
I can now simply do: `mpache [start/stop/restart]`

Answer (score 6):

### Best Solution for MAMP 3 on OSX

(should work for MAMP Pro as well).

Look inside of the folder:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin
```

You'll see the scripts used for starting and stoping Apache & MySQL.

Look inside any of the scripts:

```
start.sh or stop.sh or startApache.sh etc
```

You will see that they use the program:

`apachectl`

You can use the restart command with apachectl. So, **just set-up an alias in your ~/.bash_rc file**:

**`alias rap='sudo /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl restart'`**

rap is the acronym I gave for 'Restart Apache'. Presto! One step from the command line without having to open the MAMP application. Use the same logic if you want to set this up for MySQL.

Comment: On my version these files are here: `/Applications/MAMP/bin`

Answer (score 3):

To start it on MAMP pro version 4 it's

`/Applications/MAMP\ PRO/MAMP\ PRO.app/Contents/MacOS/MAMP\ PRO cmd startServers`

To stop it it's

`/Applications/MAMP\ PRO/MAMP\ PRO.app/Contents/MacOS/MAMP\ PRO cmd stopServers`

Sadly

Based on the advice given here

"https://deliciousbrains.com/automating-local-wordpress-site-setup-scripts-part-3-automating-rest"

And found then discovered - it's HIDDEN in the documentation right here.

https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Mac/How-Tos/General/CreateHostDatabaseCommandLine

Answer (score 3):

Nearly the same with MAMP Pro 5:

```
/Applications/MAMP\ PRO.app/Contents/MacOS/MAMP\ PRO cmd stopServers
```

start:

```
/Applications/MAMP\ PRO.app/Contents/MacOS/MAMP\ PRO cmd startServers
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MAMP PRO there is an easier way to stop MySQL.

MAMP PRO creates a shell script in your Library folder. If you've changed the password for the root user (which you should), the updated password will also be reflected in the script. The file can be found at:

~/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/stopMysql.sh

In order to type that on the command line you need to escape the spaces by adding a backslash in front of them like the command below.

### Stop MySQL Shell Script for MAMP PRO

```
~/Library/Application\ Support/appsolute/MAMP\ PRO/stopMysql.sh
```

The other thing that I found on my system was that the file didn't have the execute bit set on it. I cheated and used Path Finder to set the file as executable but you can easily find information about how to do it through the command line with chmod.

Unfortunately I can't find a proper start script created by MAMP PRO. I wanted to find something simple to use for the start command in MySQLWorkbench but for now I just left it blank because the default MAMP script does not work. I may create a script based on the helpful commands Astockwell posted in response to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I found `/Applications/MAMP PRO/MAMP PRO.app/Contents/Resources/MAMP.startup`, which works for me in MAMP PRO, with custom ports.

Just run

```
/Applications/MAMP PRO/MAMP PRO.app/Contents/Resources/MAMP.startup start
```

or

```
/Applications/MAMP PRO/MAMP PRO.app/Contents/Resources/MAMP.startup stop
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way would be to shut down and restart the application, MAMP PRO will start and stop Apache and MySQL.

start MAMP PRO

```
open -a MAMP\ PRO
```

stop MAMP PRO

```
osascript -e 'quit app "MAMP PRO"'
```

Answer (score 0):

For MAMP Pro 5 use

```
sudo /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl -f"/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/httpd.conf" -k restart
```

remember, you must use sudo

Answer (score 0):

For MAMP5.5, search for this script file in your MAMP `bin` folder: `startMysql.sh`

It would have few lines:

> #!/bin/sh
>
> /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe --port=8889
> --socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock --pid-file=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid --log-error=/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log &

Copy Paste the entire command on your OSX shell and just press enter, your Mysql server would start.

Open a new shell and start using Mysql from command line.